# How to resolve this AbstractMethodError?

Tags: java, web-services, junit

I got below error when I run junit test in the ant.
The test class needs call web service API.

Can someone help to resolve it?

```
<error message="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V" type="java.lang.AbstractMethodError">java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.newTransformerFactory(XmlUtil.java:392)
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.newTransformerFactory(XmlUtil.java:400)
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.&lt;clinit&gt;(XmlUtil.java:233)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createCatalogResolver(WSServiceDelegate.java:377)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:363)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.&lt;init&gt;(WSServiceDelegate.java:321)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.&lt;init&gt;(WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.&lt;init&gt;(WSServiceDelegate.java:211)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.&lt;init&gt;(WSServiceDelegate.java:207)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:114)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.&lt;init&gt;(Service.java:77)
at com.citi.isg.amg.ws.client.AccountManagerWs.&lt;init&gt;(AccountManagerWs.java:42)
at ... ...
```

Comment: @GhostCat,I have shared my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the root cause by myself.

Per [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html), The java.lang.AbstractMethodError is thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

Seems I have not specified the implementation for the abstract class javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in the rt.jar.

Adding below inside Junit

```
<sysproperty key="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"
                        value="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
```

make it works.

So the final Junit task looks like below:

```
<junit showoutput="true" printsummary="yes" fork="true" forkmode="once">
            <classpath refid="junit.runtime.classpath" />
            <sysproperty key="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"
                        value="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
            <batchtest haltonfailure="no" todir="${test.result.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                </fileset>
                <formatter type="xml" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate explanation specifically for `TransformerFactory.setFeature` : it appears that some implementations (e.g. xalan-2.6.0) provide TransformerFactory implementations that do not implement that method; newer versions of xalan (e.g. 2.7.3) do provide that method and the AbstractMethodError goes away.